# Trying to read the whole text file

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to read the whole contain of the txt file, not line by line, but the whole contain

and print it on screen inside a textfield in xcode

i'm using a mix of obj-c and c++ lang:

```
while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), in)!=NULL){
        cout << buff;  // this print the whole output in the console


         NSString * string = [ NSString stringWithUTF8String:buff ] ;

         [Data setStringValue:string]; // but this line only print last line inside the textfield instead of printing it all
    }
```

I'm trying to print the whole contain of the file like:

1. something...
2. something...
3. etc...

but instead it just printing the last line to the textfield, please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason you aren't using Obj-C to read the file?  It would be as simple as:

```
NSData *d = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filename];
NSString *s = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:d encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
[Data setStringValue:s];
```

Edit: To use the code you have now I would try something like this:

```
while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), in)!=NULL){
  NSMutableString *s = [[Data stringValue] mutableCopy];
  [s appendString:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:buff]];
  [Data setStringValue:s];
 }
```

Comment: Yes there is, i'm using embeded ruby script, i'm already reading the file correct, but need to display it in the textfield, not last line, but all line

Comment: +1 but for shortness you could directly use [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: filename encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error:  nil];

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri I forgot about that convenience method.  Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: It says: expected primary-expression before ']' token

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri: Better yet, `error:&myError` and then log or present the error if reading fails.

Answer (score 1):

Read a file, return the content as a C++ string:

```
  // open the file
  std::ifstream is; 
  is.open(fn.c_str(), std::ios::binary);

  // put the content in a C++ string
  std::string str((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(is)),
                   std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

In your code you are using the C api (`FILE*` from cstdio). In C, the code is more complex:

```
char * buffer = 0; // to be filled with the entire content of the file
long length;
FILE * f = fopen (filename, "rb");

if (f) // if the file was correctly opened
{
  fseek (f, 0, SEEK_END);  // seek to the end
  length = ftell (f);      // get the length of the file
  fseek (f, 0, SEEK_SET);  // seek back to the beginning
  buffer = malloc (length); // allocate a buffer of the correct size
  if (buffer)               // if allocation succeed
  {
    fread (buffer, 1, length, f);  // read 'length' octets
  }
  fclose (f); // close the file
}
```

Comment: I dont need a way to read the file, i'm already doing it right, but a way to save the contain inside one single string to be able to print it inside the textfield

Comment: Arf sorry it seems I read your question too fast. You want to do this in objective C or in C++?

Comment: @Alexman Ksa this is what this code does in fact. What do I miss ?

Comment: I'm not having a problem in reading a file, but a problem in storing all the lines as one string instead of single string with just one line

Comment: maybe i'm having problems in understanding it then, please remove the part where it search for file and read as i already did that so i can see how you doing it

Comment: @AlexmanKsa Ok, as you want. The version from sbooth is a lot less efficient though. Instead of reading the entire file once. You read pieces of it and append it each time to a string (with potential full reallocation and copy of the string)

Comment: @log0 You're right, your version would have better performance.  Whether or not it matters in practice is a question for the profiler.  I still recommend my first code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question of *why* your solution didn't work:

> ```
> [Data setStringValue:string]; // but this line only print last line inside the textfield instead of printing it all
> ```

Assuming that `Data` refers to a text field, `setStringValue:` replaces the entire contents of the field with the string you passed in. Your loop reads and sets one line at a time, so at any given time, `string` is one line from the file.

Views only get told to display when you're not doing anything else on the main thread, so your loop—assuming that you didn't run it on another thread or queue—does not print one line at a time. You read each line and replace the text field's contents with that line, so when your loop finishes, the field is left with the last thing you set its `stringValue` to—the last line from the file.

Slurping the entire file at once will work, but a couple of problems remain:

- Text fields aren't meant for displaying multiple lines. No matter how you read the file, you're still putting its contents in a place that isn't designed for such contents.
- If the file is large enough, reading it will take a significant amount of time. If you do this on the main thread, then, during that time, the app will be hung.

A proper solution would be:

1. Use a text view, not a text field. Text views are built to work with text of any number of lines, and when you create one in a nib, it comes wrapped in a scroll view for free.
2. Read the file one line or other limited-size chunk at a time, but not in a `for` or `while` loop. Use NSFileHandle or `dispatch_source`, either of which will call a block you provide whenever they read another chunk of the file.
3. Append each chunk to the text view's storage instead of replacing the entire text with it.
4. Show a progress indicator when you start reading, then hide it when you finish reading. For extra credit, make it a determinate progress bar, showing the user how far you've gotten through the file.

Comment: Great explanation!  I should strive to give more info like this instead of just code.